# How should I control leveling up in a knowledge/skill testing game?

Tags: android

I have developed a game that  tests the knowledge and skills in a series of short quiz-like games. 
Players have to move from Level 1 to Level 16 (with Level 4, 8 and 12 as major milestones~BANDS). The Difficulty level of game/questions increases at each level.
The level progression is currently based on 'POINTS'. Points in turn are based on Correct responses, faster responses, Wins, Completion etc. 
Points continue to increase for a user irrespective of Win / Loss (the duration of completing the levels varies) 
The challenge I foresee is 'every user can progress to Level 16' if he keeps on playing the game long enough (irrespective of whether he has acquired the skill/knowledge for the next level).

I am looking for a simple to understand progression rule(s) that would make lower-skilled players remain longer in that BAND before progressing to the next level and BAND. What are some best practices in Level progression that I can refer to for overcoming this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The rule of thumb of designing difficulty curves is that you want to let the players progress as soon as they have demonstrated that they possess the necessary skills for the next level.

A large number of games with a low score does not demonstrate skill (rather the opposite, in fact). A single high score in a single game might be an indicator of skill, or just that the player got lucky (this depends on your game). But a true demonstration of skill is when the player reaches a *consistently* good performance over multiple consecutive games.

So you might want to look at the players average performance in the past X challenges and have them progress when you deem it good enough to be ready for the next difficulty level. For example, instead of progressing the player to level 10 when they got 1000 points in total, have them progress when they got 100 points in the past 10 challenges they played.

A real world analogue might be professional sports. A team doesn't advance to the next league when they won X games during their whole history or when they win one game extraordinarily high. They only advance when they win enough games during one season.

Comment: Hi Philipp, Thanks for the suggestion. I like your Professionals sports analogy. My game is more a 'one season' example where the player must accumulate 100K points (on or before a target date) to reach the highest level. They can do this by (1) winning more games, (2) getting more points per game (3) scoring outstandingly well e.g. all correct, faster than opponent .. The challenge is to let players that don't perform well (lose often, score less points per game) achieve another metric before giving them a higher status (BAND).

Comment: @user87205 When your game is a competitive multiplayer game, you could consider to rate the players against each other using a system like [ELO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) and define the bands as rating percentiles (e.g. highest level are the top 1% rated players).